# cannot deploy as 'deploy' user with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano

I've reinstalled my laptop (OSX) and had to copy my public key again to the server with

```
ssh-copy-id
```

That fixed the issue for ssh'en to the server as 'acandael' user.

However, when I try to deploy my Rails app as 'deploy' user with Capistrano, I get this error message:

```
cap aborted!                                                                                         │   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@myip
```

I checked my ssh-connection to the server. I can ssh as 'acandael' user, but cannot ssh as deploy user to the server:

```
permission denied (public key)
```

I tried to fix this by running the command:

```
ssh-copy-id deploy@myip
```

but then I get the error message:

```
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new   key(s), to filter out any that are already installed                                                                                  │
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if   you are prompted now it is to│install the new keys                                                                                │
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this, so I can again deploy my application as the 'deploy' user?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Anthony

Comment: got it fixed by temporarily enabling password authentication by setting PasswordAuthentication to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Then I was able to authenticate as the deploy user to my server. After that I also need to copy my public ssh key to github. Now I can deploy my Rails app to my server.